# How to determine the pthread utilized memory

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Any given point of time, how can i get the memory size utilized by each thread?

Comment: What kind of memory are you looking for? Stack memory? Or heap memory as well?

Comment: @bdonlan Both the stack memory as well as heap memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a [heap profiler](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heapprofile.html) consider Google performance tools with their own allocator TCMalloc.

http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/

An alternative high performance allocator is jemalloc which provides statistics reporting including per-thread cache bin details with `malloc_stats_print()`

http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/index.html

Comment: Any possible way to get from /proc file system ?

Comment: @user916439 Read MK's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, the heap is shared between all threads in the process.

Answer (score 0):

To check the thread's stack size you could use non-portable GNU extension pthread_getattr_np
and also you could check /proc/self/maps (or  /proc/PID/maps) but this way is more complex.